# How to handle the if else structure for creating the concrete class in strategy pattern

Tags: python, design-patterns, factory-pattern, strategy-pattern

I am new to design pattern.

My current code without strategy pattern:

```
def get_src_data(type):

  if type == "obj1":  
    return fetch_src_obj1()  
  elif type == "obj2":  
    return fetch_src_obj2()

    ...    
    
    ...    
    
    ...
```

after applying strategy pattern, I have created a concrete class for each type of object source which implements a common interface and created a context class via which the user can access the concrete class. Now I have to pass the concrete class to the context to get the data. This Works!!

```
class AbsStrategy(ABC):
   @abstractmethod
   def get_src_data():
     pass

class Context(AbsStrategy):
  def __init__(strategy):
    self.strategy = strategy
  def process_data(strategy):
    self.strategy.get_src_data()
```

But for creating the concrete class I am again forced to create the if else/dict mapping for creating the concrete class instance.

I found factory pattern can provide a solution over here, but couldn't find any easier example to comprehend. Hence like to have a help from the community

Comment: It might help to show the undesirable `if` ladder for creating the class instances.